# How do you combine filter conditions

Tags: haskell, filter

The filter class of functions takes a condition (a -> Bool) and applies it when filtering.

What is the best way to use a filter on when you have multiple conditions?

Used the applicative function
liftA2 instead of liftM2 because I for some reason didn't understand how liftM2 worked within pure code.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The liftM2 combinator can be used in the Reader monad to do this in a 'more functional' way:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader

-- ....

filter (liftM2 (&&) odd (> 100)) [1..200]
```

Note that the imports are important; Control.Monad.Reader provides the Monad (e ->) instance that makes this all work.

The reason this works is the reader monad is just (e ->) for some environment e. Thus, a boolean predicate is a 0-ary monadic function returning bool in an environment corresponding to its argument. We can then use liftM2 to distribute the environment over two such predicates.

Or, in simpler terms, liftM2 will act a bit like this when the types work out:

```
liftM2 f g h a = f (g a) (h a)
```

You can also define a new combinator if you want to be able to chain these easily, and/or don't want to mess with liftM2:

```
(.&&.) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
(.&&.) f g a = (f a) && (g a)
-- or, in points-free style:
(.&&.) = liftM2 (&&)    

filter (odd .&&. (> 5) .&&. (< 20)) [1..100]
```

Comment: Both examples work on GHC 7.6.3 even if you don't import `Control.Monad.Reader`.

Comment: I’m `liftM2` can (nowadays) be replaced like this: `filter ((&&) <$> odd <*> (>100)) [1.200]`. Which is the same, but prettier. :) It also only requires `Control.Applicative`, and  no full monads. … Although  I still wonder what operator allows ANDing more than two Boolean functions…

Answer (score 22):

Well, you can combine functions however you want in Haskell (as long as the types are correct) and using lambdas you don't even have to name your predicate function, i.e.,

```
filter (\x -> odd x && x > 100) [1..200]
```

Answer (score 11):

Let's say your conditions are stored in a list called `conditions`. This list has the type `[a -> Bool]`.

To apply all conditions to a value `x`, you can use `map`:

```
map ($ x) conditions
```

This applies each condition to `x` and returns a list of Bool. To reduce this list into a single boolean, True if all elements are True, and False otherwise, you can use the `and` function:

```
and $ map ($ x) conditions
```

Now you have a function that combines all conditions. Let's give it a name:

```
combined_condition x = and $ map ($ x) conditions
```

This function has the type `a -> Bool`, so we can use it in a call to `filter`:

```
filter combined_condition [1..10]
```

Comment: Careful with ($x) as opposed to ($ x), as if you turn on Template Haskell for some other reason the $x will suddenly look like a splice.

Comment: You've discovered the `all` function: `filter (all conditions) [1..10]`

Comment: There's also the any function, depending on how you want to combine the predicates:
any p =  or  . map p;
all p =  and . map p;

Comment: @Peter: all has type (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool, not [(a -> Bool)] -> a -> Bool.

Comment: @Peter as Stephan202 pointed out, 'all' applies one condition to a list of values. My function applies a list of conditions to a single value.

Comment: ```filter (and . sequence conditions)```

Comment: Still, instead of `and $ map ($ x) conditions` it's possible to type: `all ($ x) conditions`

Comment: `and (map ($ x) conditions)` can be written `and (conditions ?? x)` with [`(??)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list of filtering functions of type `a -> Bool` and want to combine them into one concise filtering function of the same type, we can write functions to do just. Which of the two functions below that you use will depend on the filter behavior you need.

```
anyfilt :: [(a -> Bool)] -> (a -> Bool)
anyfilt fns = \el -> any (\fn -> fn el) fns

allfilt :: [(a -> Bool)] -> (a -> Bool)
allfilt fns = \el -> all (\fn -> fn el) fns
```

`anyfilt` will return **true if any of the filter functions return true** and false if all of the filter functions return false.
`allfilt` will return true if all of the filter functions return true and **false if any of the filter functions return false**.
Note that you cannot η-reduce either function as the references to `fns` on the RHS are within anonymous functions.

Use it like this:

```
filterLines :: [String] -> [String]
filterLines = let
  isComment = isPrefixOf "# "
  isBlank = (==) ""
  badLine = anyfilt([isComment, isBlank])
  in filter (not . badLine)

main = mapM_ putStrLn $ filterLines ["# comment", "", "true line"]
--> "true line"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another one, using function functors, which easily extends to a greater number of conditions:

```
filter (and <$> sequence [odd, (> 100)]) [1..200]
```