# How could I filter for many conditions in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

the function definition is already given

```
filterMany :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
filterMany (f:fs) [] = []
filterMany (f:fs) (x)
  | filter (f) x == True = x : filter (fs) x
  | otherwise = filter (fs) x
```

the output should be:

```
filterMany [even, odd] [1..10] == []
filterMany [even, (\x -> x `mod` 4 /= 0)] [1..10] == [2,6,10]
filterMany [(<7), (>3), odd] [1..20] == [5]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you combine filter conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841851/how-do-you-combine-filter-conditions)

Comment: You should make a recursive call to `filterMany`, not to `filter`. Remove `== True`, it's redundant. Parentheses in `(variable)` are also redundant.

Comment: do you mean: 
    filterMany' (f:fs) [] = []
    filterMany' (f:fs) x
      | f x = x : filterMany' fs x
      | otherwise = filterMany' fs x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) here to check if *all* conditions are met. We thus can implement this with:

```
filterMany :: Foldable f => f (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterMany fs = filter (\x -> all ($ x) fs)
```

We here thus apply all predicates with parameter `x` by specifying `all ($ x) fs`. If all these predicates hold, then we retrain the element `x`.

For example:

```
Prelude> filterMany [even, odd] [1..10]
[]
Prelude> filterMany [even, (\x -> x `mod` 4 /= 0)] [1..10]
[2,6,10]
Prelude> filterMany [(<7), (>3), odd] [1..20]
[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
filterMany :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
filterMany [] (x:xs) = (x:xs)
filterMany (f:fs) (x:xs) = filter f (filterMany (fs) (x:xs))
```